# I can't put my friend's PS4 account as principal on my PS4

Tags: ps4

I want to add as principal account my friend's account in order to share games and PS plus, but when I try to make him as principal the system tells me that I have already a PS4 account set as principal, but it's not true.

I've already tried to remove all the accounts that I have in the PS4 but it still doesen't work.

Comment: Have you checked that your friend's account is not set as principal on another console?

Comment: yes, is set as principal only on his console

Comment: Then try to remove his account as principal on his console, and try again on yours

Comment: @pinkerman thanks i'll try